# data.table aggregation with custom function returning a named list

Tags: r, data.table

I have a following data table:

```
dt = data.table(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
```

I'd like to aggregate both columns with a custom function that returns a list or a vector of stats such as mean, sd, etc. The desired output would be:

```
                x       y
1: Mean       5.5    15.5
2: SD     3.02765 3.02765
```

So far I've got this snippet:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {list('Mean' = mean(x), 'SD' = sd(x))}), .SDcols = c('x','y')]
```

which produces the stats but I also would like row names according to those specified in the list.

Comment: `f <- function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), SD = sd(x)) ; dt[, sapply(.SD, f)]`

Comment: another option: `melt(dt)[, .(Mean = mean(value), Sd = sd(value)), by = variable]`

Comment: David's answer/comment works bc it uses `sapply` which simplifies the result to a matrix. When substituting `sapply` with `lapply` in his approach, you end up with a `data.table` again and those don't have row.names

Comment: Great, sapply is the way to go!

Comment: @DavidA Might as well post that, eh? Also, can simplify to `sapply(dt, f)`